# Почему корявый Export из Blender в Unity и как это исправить?

Tags: unity3d, blender

Скриншот из Blender:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот из Unity:[image: c]

- Она плохая только в Unity, а в Blender после import он такая же как и была.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В юнити полигоны односторонние, с одной стороны их не видно. В блендере тоже есть такой режим, Backface Culling, но гораздо виднее развернутые полигоны в другом режиме. Включите в оверлеях Face Orientation, фейсы повернутые изнанкой будут отображаться красным. Вам необходимо развернуть эти полигоны.

Обычно помогает операция <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> все полигоны нужно выделить перед этим. Если объект Manifold, она развернет все нормали в одну сторону. Если нет, выделите неправильные полигоны и нажмите <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> -> Flip normals